# Getting logged off on Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

We have an ASP.NET MVC3 based Web role running on the Azure cloud, using Forms Authentication.

Occasionally we have noticed that users that are logged in will get logged out automatically without any action (while the browser window is open).

Has anyone else seen this? Any ideas as to why this might be happening?

It has been observed on multiple machines for multiple users using multiple browsers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not much to go on, here, but...

- Are you running multiple instances? If so, did you set up SQL Azure or Cache as your Session Provider? If not, you'd have two sets of session state, and depending on which VM instance you hit, your user's session state may or may not be present.
- Is the logout happening after 20 minutes of inactivity? That's the default timeout for the AppPool before it recycles.
- Does this happen in the Compute Emulator as well as when you deploy?

Answer (score 1):

Since the windows azure network load balancing doesn't support affinity, each single client request will be redirected to any node instance. If you don't use SQL Azure or Azure AppFabric Cache as Session Provider, each instance will have his asp.net session in-memory. Then each in-memory session will be invisible to other instances.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely either you are running InProc for your Session and when the users go to a new server they are having to log in again or your server is restarting for some reason.  If you are using InProc, switch to AppFabric Caching and if you are using that already, log into the box and check the event logs to see if the process is restarting (look for an unhandled exception).